# Add more rows to the total reputation user leagues

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-leagues

The [all-time reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2010-07-20) has a table with total reputation per user:

[image: Total Rep per user]

On Stack Overflow, there are now 749 users with 100,000+ reputation.

It would be nice to have a couple of extra entries to this table, perhaps 250k and 500k.